# Trying to get from $\frac{\pi\cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt{\cos^2(\pi x)}}$, to, $\pi \sqrt{\cos^2(\pi x)} \sec(\pi x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I'm trying to manipulate; $\frac{\pi\cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt{\cos^2(\pi x)}}$; to; $\pi \sqrt{\cos^2(\pi x)} \sec(\pi x)$. ~ (From Wolfram but no steps).

When I try I get $\frac{\pi\cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt{\cos^2(\pi x)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^2(\pi x)}}\cdot \frac{\pi}{\sec(\pi x)} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\cos^2(\pi x)}sec(\pi x)}$.

I'm unsure what else I can do.

~ Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally notice that
$$\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2}}=\frac{t\cdot \sqrt{t^2}}{\sqrt{t^2}\cdot \sqrt{t^2}}=\frac{t \sqrt{t^2}}{t^2}=\frac{1}{t}\cdot \sqrt{t^2}$$

Apply this for $t=\cos \pi x$ and don't forget $\frac{1}{t}=\sec \pi x$

Answer (score 0):

since $\frac { \cos  (\pi x) }{ \left| \cos  (\pi x) \right|  } =\frac { \left| \cos  (\pi x) \right|  }{ \cos  (\pi x) } $
$$\frac { \pi \cos  (\pi x) }{ \sqrt { \cos ^{ 2 } (\pi x) }  } =\pi \frac { \cos  (\pi x) }{ \left| \cos  (\pi x) \right|  } =\pi \frac { \left| \cos  (\pi x) \right|  }{ \cos  (\pi x) } =\pi \sqrt { \cos ^{ 2 } (\pi x) } \sec { \left( \pi x \right)  } $$